# Repeat background image in Nav Bar

Tags: css, web, navigation, background-image

I would like to include the repeated background image that is on my background to my navigation bar as well.

```
#navigation-top, #navigation-bottom {
background-color: #fff;
width: 100%;
}
```

http://www.sanisportwest.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem on your site is that "image.jpg" does not exist.

```
#navigation-top, #navigation-bottom {
    background: #fff url('path/to/image.jpg') repeat;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you only want it to repeat left to right (and not up and down), use `repeat-x`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `repeat-x` or `repeat-y`, depending on the orientation of your image and Nav bar.  Assuming your Nav bar is horizontal:

```
#navigation-top, #navigation-bottom {
width: 100%;
background: url(images/background_image.gif) repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background: #ffffff url("yourimg") repeat-x;
```

Answer (score -1):

Copy all of the background related CSS from `#canvas-wrapper` and paste it into `#navigation-top`, `#navigation-bottom`.

Comment: Don't cut an paste when a comma will do.  #canvas-wrapper, #navigation-top, #navigation-bottom { ... }